# When using React Query returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

So im learning **React Query** and i have write all the code the way it needs to be written this is the code inside App component

```
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const queryclient = new QueryClient();

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col w-[70%] justify-center items-center">
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryclient}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Mainpage />} />
            <Route path="/add" element={<Shtoprod />} />
            <Route path="/hiq" element={<Hiqprod />} />
            <Route
              path="*"
              element={
                <h1 className="text-warning font-primaryFont font-bold text-8xl my-10">
                  Faqja nuk u gjetë
                </h1>
              }
            />
          </Routes>
          <Form />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is the code inside component that im trying to use **React Query**

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const { produktet } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["gjerat"],
    queryFn: () => {
      return Axios.get("http://localhost:3500/dat").then((res) => res.data);
    },
  });

console.log(`Prod: ${produktet}`);
```

This code is insede a component

I try to get data from json-server but when i use **React Query** it always return's undefined but when i try with other things like Axios ore fetch it work's.I want to know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to destructure the `data` property instead of `produktet` from the `useQuery` hook:

```
const { data: produktet, isLoading, error } = useQuery("gjerat", fetchProducts);
```

Comment: @rMonterio thanks! this worked but im confused why because in youtube tutorials no one have done this